# Does sbt have something like gradle's processResources task with ReplaceTokens support?

Tags: sbt

We are moving into Scala/SBT from a Java/Gradle stack. Our gradle builds were leveraging a task called processResources and some Ant filter thing named ReplaceTokens to dynamically replace tokens in a checked-in .properties file without actually changing the .properties file (just changing the output). The gradle task looks like:

```
processResources {
  def whoami = System.getProperty( 'user.name' );
  def hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
  def buildTimestamp = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')

  filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
          "buildsig.version" : project.version,
          "buildsig.classifier" : project.classifier,
          "buildsig.timestamp" : buildTimestamp,
          "buildsig.user" : whoami,
          "buildsig.system" : hostname,
          "buildsig.tag" : buildTag
      ]
}
```

This task locates all the template files in the src/main/resources directory, performs the requisite substitutions and outputs the results at build/resources/main.  In other words it transforms src/main/resources/buildsig.properties from...

```
buildsig.version=@buildsig.version@
buildsig.classifier=@buildsig.classifier@
buildsig.timestamp=@buildsig.timestamp@
buildsig.user=@buildsig.user@
buildsig.system=@buildsig.system@
buildsig.tag=@buildsig.tag@
```

...to build/resources/main/buildsig.properties...

```
buildsig.version=1.6.5
buildsig.classifier=RELEASE
buildsig.timestamp=2013-05-06 09:46:52 PDT
buildsig.user=jenkins
buildsig.system=bobk-mbp.local
buildsig.tag=dev
```

Which, ultimately, finds its way into the WAR file at WEB-INF/classes/buildsig.properties.  This works like a champ to record build specific information in a Properties file which gets loaded from the classpath at runtime.

What do I do in SBT to get something like this done?  I'm new to Scala / SBT so please forgive me if this seems a stupid question.  At the end of the day what I need is a means of pulling some information from the environment on which I build and placing that information into a properties file that is classpath loadable at runtime.  Any insights you can give to help me get this done are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you do this with Plug-Ins?  https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sbt-buildinfo` is a good option.  The [README](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo#usage) shows an example of how to define custom mappings and mappings that should run on each compile.  In addition to the straightforward addition of normal settings like `version` shown there, you want a section like this:

```
buildInfoKeys ++= Seq[BuildInfoKey](
    "hostname" -> java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(),
    "whoami" -> System.getProperty("user.name"),
    BuildInfoKey.action("buildTimestamp") {
        java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.format(new java.util.Date())
    }
)
```

Comment: Sigh.  Too good to be true.  sbt-buildinfo manages to generate a BuildInfo class file with the info, which is what I wanted.  The problem is that generation is somehow causing Play 2.1.1 to RELOAD the whole app on every request!  This only happens in "play run" but not when I run the app from a "play dist" distribution.  Make Bob sad.

Comment: This is probably from the buildTimestamp, which will change the contents of BuildInfo each time a task is run, causing it to get recompiled and causing a reload.  I'm not sure of all the interactions, so you might ask a new question highlighting sbt-buildinfo, a build timestamp, and tag it with playframework (or whatever the right tag is).

Comment: Yep, that's the culprit.  I'm between a rock and a hard place regarding what to do about it.  I'm leaning back towards the gradle/ant solution which was to post-process the compiled artifacts only when a specific task was being executed.  In any event, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd like to see this work and I'm sure the Play and build-info devs do as well.  Would you mind explaining how to reproduce?  a) play project b) build info with the above configuration c) play run d) ???

Answer (score 2):

Would the following be what you're looking for:

[sbt-editsource: An SBT plugin for editing files](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-editsource/)

> sbt-editsource is a text substitution plugin for SBT 0.11.x and
>   greater. In a way, it’s a poor man’s sed(1), for SBT. It provides the
>   ability to apply line-by-line substitutions to a source text file,
>   producing an edited output file. It supports two kinds of edits:
>
> Variable substitution, where ${var} is replaced by a value. sed-like
>   regular expression substitution.

This is from [Community Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/Community-Plugins.html).

Comment: That's interesting, to be sure, but I'm pretty sure https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo does what I need, now I just need to learn how to wield it.  Thanks.