# sbt token replacement in resources

Tags: scala, gradle, build, sbt

I want to replace build-dependent information in certain resource files (e.g. in `src/main/resources`). In Gradle, I can do this:

```
processResources {
    // apply replacements in meta.cfg
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "meta.cfg"
        expand "version": project.version, "build": System.env.BUILD
    }

    // just copy everything else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude "meta.cfg"
    }
}
```

Using this, occurrences of `${version}` and `${build}` are replaced by their respective values known at build time.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491347/does-sbt-have-something-like-gradles-processresources-task-with-replacetokens-s), `sbt-buildinfo` and `sbt-editsource` are suggested, but they only provide workarounds of the general problem "How do I inject build info in my code?" and do not solve this specific problem.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in sbt?